# Oracle Forms 11g buit-ins

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

*Oracle Forms 11g* that *built-ins* does not work : `set_item_property('bt_block.T_DTH_PLACE_HSPTL_LOCATION',database_item,property_false);` 
please help me solve this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by *"built-ins does not work"* ? Please provide error messages or describe what happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is no property called `database_item` in **Oracle Forms** to be set at the *item level*.

Instead of that you can try below code :

```
set_item_property('bt_block.T_DTH_PLACE_HSPTL_LOCATION',insert_allowed,property_false); 
set_item_property('bt_block.T_DTH_PLACE_HSPTL_LOCATION',update_allowed,property_false);
```